# Match an Array in F#

Tags: f#

I want to pattern match on the command line arguments array.

What I want to do is have a case that matches any case where there's at least one parameter or more and put that first parameter in a variable and then have another case that handles when there are no parameters.

```
match argv with
    | [| first |] -> // this only matches when there is one
    | [| first, _ |] -> // this only matches when there is two
    | [| first, tail |] -> // not working
    | argv.[first..] -> // this doesn't compile
    | [| first; .. |] -> // this neither
    | _ -> // the other cases
```

Comment: easiest way is to convert to a list

Comment: OT, but if you need help with parsing args, check out the excellent Argu library https://fsprojects.github.io/Argu/

Comment: Attempting this with arrays would lead to O(n) performance for each iteration (due to the recreation of an array each time of the size-minus-one), as opposed to O(1) for each iteration with lists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [use `truncate`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/10/11/CheckingforexactlyoneiteminasequenceusingCandF):

```
match args |> Array.truncate 1 with
| [| x |] -> x
| _       -> "No arguments"
```

Answer (score 8):

If you convert `argv` to a list using `Array.toList`, you can then pattern match on it as a list using the [cons operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx#Anchor_1), `::`:

```
match argv |> Array.toList with
    | x::[]  -> printfn "%s" x
    | x::xs  -> printfn "%s, plus %i more" x (xs |> Seq.length)
    | _  -> printfn "nothing"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the first item, I prefer `Array.tryHead`:

```
match Array.tryHead items with
| Some head -> printfn "%O" head
| None -> printfn "%s" "No items"
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing you'll get without converting to a list is:

```
match argv with
| arr when argv.Length > 0 ->
    let first = arr.[0]
    printfn "%s" first
| _ -> printfn "none"
```